# Tomcat and SSL Client certificate

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I would like to have a following scenario:

1. create my own CA
2. create a server certificate and sign it with my CA
3. create multiple client certificates and sign them with my CA

Next i would like to authenticate every client which presents a certificate signed by my CA.

Is it possible to realize such scenario without adding every single client certificate to my tomcat keystore? I just would like to only verify if the certificate the client presents is issued and signed by my CA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's certainly possible, and I have done exactly this.  If you configure Tomcat with a truststore containing your CA certificate then it should accept any client certificate signed by that CA.

I'll assume you have your CA key and root certificate already generated and you know how to use it to turn CSRs into certificates.

First generate your server key, and a corresponding CSR

```
$ openssl genrsa -out XXX.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -nodes -key XXX.key -out XXX.csr
```

Use your CA certificate to sign the CSR, producing a server certificate `XXX.crt`.  Now package the server key, server cert and CA cert into a single PKCS#12 file

```
$ cat XXX.crt ca-certificate.pem | openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey XXX.key -out XXX.p12 -name tomcat -caname myauthority
```

You will be prompted for several passwords by this process, set them all to the same value (it doesn't matter what this value is and it doesn't have to be a secure password, it just has to be non-empty - I use `changeit`).

This `.p12` file can now act as the *keystore* for Tomcat.  Next you need to create a separate JKS keystore containing just the CA certificate to use as the *truststore*.

```
$ keytool -import -alias myauthority -keystore truststore.jks -file ca-certificate.pem
```

Again, reply to all password prompts with the same non-empty password, such as `changeit`.

Finally you can configure Tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/XXX.p12"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           keystorePass="changeit"
           truststoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/truststore.jks"
           truststoreType="JKS"
           truststorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Comment: In addition, if you don't know how to deal with a CA, you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11558192/372643) (including comments for links to tools): the hardest is the administrative part.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: Use self-signed root certificate only in development environment.**

For a more complete overview (step-by-step):

```
Create a root certificate
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 365

Create a key and CSR
openssl genrsa -out mycert.key 2048
openssl req -new -nodes -key mycert.key -out mycert.csr

Sign the CSR with your root certificate
openssl x509 -req -in mycert.csr -CA cert.pem -CAkey key.pem -CAcreateserial -out mycert.pem

Create a PKCS#12 certificate with the cert and key
openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycert.p12 -inkey mycert.key -in mycert.pem

Create a separate JKS keystore containing just the CA certificate (to use as the truststore)
keytool -import -alias my-ca -keystore truststore.jks -file cert.pem
```

This works with the Tomcat configuration of Ian Roberts.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at openSSL : http://openssl.org/
Or if you want an existing CA for free (but you have to do it each month) there's : http://www.startssl.com/

Comment: This is for client certificates.  There are extremely few cases in which it's appropriate and sane to use the normal internet PKI for client certificates used for authentication to a service.

Comment: perhaps only where you have an airgap network and you are connecting two machines to each other, and not to the internet.